# Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError

Tags: java, spring, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I created a service Restful With Spring framework , and I'm trying to include a method a call to Selenium Java, with the driver Google Chrome , but to create the object  `WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver ();`

**This me generates a exception :**

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.triggerAfterCompletionWithError(DispatcherServlet.java:1302)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:977)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:968)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:859)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:844)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
causa raíz

java.lang.StackOverflowError
    java.lang.Exception.<init>(Exception.java:102)
    java.lang.ReflectiveOperationException.<init>(ReflectiveOperationException.java:89)
    java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException.<init>(InvocationTargetException.java:72)
    sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor95.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    org.json.JSONObject.populateMap(JSONObject.java:1015)
    org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:279)
    org.json.JSONObject.wrap(JSONObject.java:1527)
    org.json.JSONObject.populateMap(JSONObject.java:1017)
    org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:279)
    org.json.JSONObject.wrap(JSONObject.java:1527)
    org.json.JSONObject.populateMap(JSONObject.java:1017)
    org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:279)
    org.json.JSONObject.wrap(JSONObject.java:1527)
```

Independent in a main class runs smoothly , but I require it from a service Restful

Comment: Could you include a snippet of your code where it runs smoothly, and another snipper where it throws the exception?

Answer (score 4):

I spent few hours struggling with stackoverflow error ... hope this helps someone

i made a silly mistake

please see below code snippet :-

Incorrect code :-

```
Map abcWithKey = new HashMap<>();

abcWithKey.put("key_1", abcWithKey);
```

Correct Code :-

```
Map abcWithKey = new HashMap<>();

abcWithKey.put("key_1", abc);
```

where abc is a map , so instead of adding abc(different map) i was adding same map recursively.

Answer (score 1):

Each thread in a Java application has its own stack, a place where method calls and local variables are stored. The error you mention usually happens when this stack is full, basically the current thread makes a lot of calls to certain methods (this is the happy case; another facet would be an infinite loop).

Try to run the java process with a higher stack size and see if the error happens again. This can be set using the -Xss property: -Xss4m